# Dual boot. No boot option!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 from a live CD and when it was finished it restarted but didn't give me the option to boot Windows... Ubuntu booted automatic. I ran the command:

`sudo parted /dev/sda/ print`

and here are the results:

```
drenii@Drenii:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
[sudo] password for drenii: 
Model: ATA ST320LT012-9WS14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      106MB   186GB  186GB   primary   ntfs
 3      186GB   188GB  2499MB  extended
 5      186GB   188GB  2499MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 4      188GB   320GB  132GB   primary   ext4
```

Someone please help as I need windows.

Comment: Then please add the solution as an aswer.

Comment: I dont know the solution... i was thanking him for fixing the post because it was a disorder... still googling for a solituion.